# picking dl directory w/ youtube_dl

Tags: python, youtube-dl

Using youtube_dl, I'm writing an interface tool that downloads video.

I import youtube_dl and run,

```
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([address])
```

However I remain uncertain as to how I specify download directory using youtube_dl alone. What is the option or command framed for Python

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the [embedding instructions](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl) of youtube-dl, you can find the list of all options in [YoutubeDL.py](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L129-L279).

In your case, try

```
import youtube_dl

address = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'
opts = {
   'outtmpl': '/my/download/directory/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s',
}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([address])
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#filesystem-options) for more information about `outtmpl`.

Comment: does it expect a dictionary for options, or should that be `**opts`?

Comment: @WayneWerner I am unsure why you would think that it should be `**opts`. The code works as is, [the embedding tutorial](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl) uses a dictionary, the [constructor of YoutubeDL](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L289) has the signature `self, params=None, auto_init=True`, and I when I created the youtube-dl API I decided to use a dict.

Comment: I didn't know *you* are the one behind youtube-dl. It's an excellent tool :) *most* apis that I've encountered take arguments rather than a dictionary, but if it takes a dictionary then it takes a dictionary. Carry on.